# Access violation (0xC0000005) at EIP=0x3052D62C

Tags: labview

I had this error when i tried to run application (EXE) file create from vi.

Access violation (0xC0000005) at EIP=0x3052D62C
Version: 1.0.0.0

I have already repaired LabView but still the same error appear, any help?

Thank you in advance,
Thanya

Comment: Did you contact the vendor? Do you mind sharing other useful information like the version of LabView and information about your system?

Comment: Are you trying to run the executable on a different computer and if so does it have the right versions of the LabVIEW run-time engine installed, as well as any other components such as NI-DAQ or VISA, or any DLL’s your application needs?

Answer (score 1):

These errors are usually due to bugs in LabVIEW rather than your code. I would get in touch with your local branch of National Instruments. They can check their bug database and see if they know what the underlying problem is and may be able to suggest a way to avoid it.

If it only happens in an EXE one trick is to try going to the additional exclusions section of the build and make sure that everything is included in case something is being missed as a requirement in the compiler but this is a long shot.

James

Comment: A google search for "Access violation (0xC0000005)" leads to this NI Knowledgebase entry: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/CE69D2C55480900486257B6A0037C327. In this case, the problem is most likely NOT a bug in LabVIEW, but rather an implementation issue.

Comment: True, I had forgotten about that case that can see these as well, If you are using the call library function node this could also be a cause but the fact that it only happens in the exe is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem, Program was running fine in LabVIEW but exe was throwing Access Violation Error.

Solution:Wire .dll path externally to CLFN node rather than specifying in node.

Open CLFN Node->Click on 'Specify Paths on Diagram'-> Wire path to clfn node. Build exe and run the application.

Answer (score 0):

*I was facing same problem, Program was running fine in LabVIEW but exe was throwing Access Violation Error.
Solution:Wire .dll path externally to CLFN node rather than specifying in node.
Open CLFN Node->Click on 'Specify Paths on Diagram'-> Wire path to clfn node. Build exe and run the application.
SwapnilG
1*
**Above mentioned method has worked in my applications and crash issues are disappeared, now!**